# Periods of Heavy Speciation

Tags: evolution, genetics, microrna

I have a set of microRNA ages with corresponding labels suggesting which clade they first emerged from. For instance, for hsa-mir-1, let's say, it would have an age of Eutheria. I have several peaks in the distributions of my age. One idea I had was to check to see if these peaks correspond to periods of intense specialization. For instance, the Eutheria clade saw a vast diversification of species relative to other clades. I'd like to determine this from a more computational perspective rather than Googling each clade.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is? You want to phylogenetically classify using microRNAs??

Answer (score 1):

My guess (as your question need heavy editing!!) would be [MiRdup](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~blanchem/mirdup/).

> MiRdup Goals:
>
> - Validation of pre-miRNAs predictions
> - Prediction of mature miRNA
>
> Abstract: MicroRNAs (miRNAs) are short RNA species derived from hairpin-forming miRNA precursors (pre-miRNA)
>   and acting as key post-transcriptional regulators. Most computational
>   tools labeled as miRNA predictors are in fact pre-miRNA predictors and
>   provide no information about the putative miRNA location within the
>   pre-miRNA. Sequence and structural features that determine the
>   location of the miRNA, and the extent to which these properties vary
>   from species to species, are poorly understood. We have developed
>   miRdup, a computational predictor for the identification of the most
>   likely miRNA location within a given pre-miRNA or the validation of a
>   candidate miRNA. MiRdup is based on a random forest classifier trained
>   with experimentally validated miRNAs from miRbase, with features that
>   characterize the miRNA-miRNA* duplex